# mysqli prepared statement num_rows returns 0 while query returns greater than 0

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a simple prepared statement for an email that actually exists:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "test");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$sql = 'SELECT `email` FROM `users` WHERE `email` = ?';
$email = 'example@hotmail.com';

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)) {
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
    $stmt->execute();

    if ($stmt->num_rows) {
        echo 'hello';
    }

    echo 'No user';
}
```

Result: echos `No user` when it should echo `hello`

I ran the same query in the console and got a result using same email as above.

I tested using a simple mysqli query as well:

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = 'example@hotmail.com'")) {
    echo 'hello';

}
```

Result: what I expected `hello`

Also `$result`'s `num_rows` is 1.

Why is the prepared statment's  `num_row` not greater than 0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you execute a statement through mysqli, the results are not actually in PHP until you fetch them -- the results are held by the DB engine. So the `mysqli_stmt` object has no way to know how many results there are immediately after execution.

Modify your code like so:

```
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result(); // pull results into PHP memory

// now you can check $stmt->num_rows;
```

[See the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php)

This doesn't apply to your particular example, but if your result set is large, `$stmt->store_result()` will consume a lot of memory. In this case, if all you care about is figuring out whether at least one result was returned, don't store results; instead, just check whether the result metadata is not null:

```
$stmt->execute();
$hasResult = $stmt->result_metadata ? true : false;
```

[See the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.result-metadata.php)

Answer (score 2):

I think it's missing

```
$stmt->store_result();

if ($stmt->num_rows) {
    echo 'hello';
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php

Answer (score 1):

call function $stmt->store_result() after  $stmt->execute() 
this link might help http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php